# How to specify request headers in API Blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint

I am trying to define an API blueprint for a resource that utilises request headers to understand what content type to return.

```
## Offer [/offers/{offerCode}]

+ Parameters
    + offerCode: summer2015 (required, string) - alphanumeric offer code

### View an Offer Detail [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/vnd.v0.1.0+json)

    {
        ........
    }
```

I want my request to be as follows:-

```
GET /offers/summer2015 HTTP/1.1
Host: my.api.com
Accept: application/vnd.v0.1.0+json
```

How can I document that using API Blueprint?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want to achieve but I'd say that you want to specify header for request and you can do that by specifying request the same way as response.

```
## Offer [/offers/{offerCode}]

+ Parameters
    + offerCode: summer2015 (required, string) - alphanumeric offer code


### View an Offer Detail [GET]

+ Request 

    + Headers 

          Accept: application/vnd.v0.1.0+json 


+ Response 200 (application/vnd.v0.1.0+json)

    {
        ........
    }
```